# NotesException: A required argument has not been provided

Tags: java, xpages

My XPage gathers information which I use to populate a document in a different Domino database.  I use a link button (so I can open another XPage after submission). The onClick code is as follows:

```
 var rtn = true
 var util = new utilities()
 var hostURL = configBean.getValue("HostURL");
var userAttachment;
//set up info needed for checking duplicates
var attachName=getComponent("attachmentIdentifier").getValue();
var serialNbr = getComponent("serialNumber").getValue();
userAttachment = user+"~"+attachName;
var userSerial = user+"~"+serialNbr;
//Done setting info needed
//check for duplicates
rtn = utilBean.checkAttachmentName(userAttachment, userSerial)
//done
if(rtn==true){
 var doc:Document = document1;
 dBar.info("ALL IS GOOD");
 var noteID:String=document1.getNoteID();
 dBar.info("Calling saveNewAttachment using NoteID " + noteID )
 rtn=utilBean.saveNewAttachment(session,noteID );  //<<< I get error here
 dBar.info("rtn = " + rtn)
 return "xsp-success";
 view.postScript("window.open('"+sessionScope.nextURL+"')")
}else if (rtn==false){
 errMsgArray = utilBean.getErrorMessages();
 for(err in errMsgArray){
 //for (i=0; i < errMsgArray.size(); i++){
     dBar.info("err: "+ err.toString());
     if (err== "nameUsed"){
         //send message to XPXage
         facesContext.addMessage(attachmentIdentifier.getClientId(facesContext) , msg(langBean.getValue("duplicateName")));
     }
         if(err=="serialUsed"){
             //send message to XPXage
             facesContext.addMessage(serialNumber.getClientId(facesContext) , msg(langBean.getValue("duplicateSerial")));
     }
 }

 return "xsp-failure";
}
```

And the java code that delivers the error is this

```
public boolean saveNewAttachment(Session ses, String noteID)
throws NotesException {
debugMsg("Entering saveNewAttachment and  NOTEID = "+noteID);
// this is used when the user saves an attachment to to the
// user profiles db
boolean rtn = false;
Document  doc;
ConfigBean configBean = (ConfigBean)         
ExtLibUtil.resolveVariable(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), 
"configBean");
String dbName = (String) configBean.getValue("WebsiteDbPath");
debugMsg("A");
Database thisDB = ses.getDatabase(ses.getServerName(), dbName, false);
String value;
try {
debugMsg("noteID:  "+noteID);
```

The next line throws the NotesException error

```
doc = thisDB.getDocumentByID("noteID");
debugMsg("C");
} catch (Exception e) {
debugMsg("utilitiesBean.saveAttachment: " + e.toString());
e.printStackTrace();
System.out.println("utilitiesBean.saveAttachment: " + e.toString());
throw new RuntimeException("utilitiesBean.saveAttachment: "
    + e.toString());
}
 return rtn;
}
```

I might be going about this wrong.  I want to save the document which the data is bound to the User Profile database but if I submit it I need to redirect it to a different page.  That is why I am using a link, however, I am having a hard time trying to get the document saved.

Answer (score 1):

Has `document1` been saved before this code is called? If not, it's not in the backend database to retrieve via `getDocumentByID()`.

I'm assuming this line has been copied into here incorrectly, because "noteID" is not a NoteID or a variable holding a NoteID, it's a string.

`doc = thisDB.getDocumentByID("noteID");`

Comment: Oops,  you are correct.  I need to remove the quote marks but that is a not the real problem.  I have not tried to save the document yet so I will try to do that first.